# Web.config: Redirect from http to https

Tags: web-config

I'm new to ASP.NET, i have developed a website and hosted it on GoDaddy.
Is it possible to have a folder under the website requires an https to access it or any file under it? in other words, when any file is loaded from that folder the URL address will turn into HTTPS://

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Decorate the controller which provides access to those URLs with `[RequireHttps]`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `http://www.dantor.com/support/misc/web-config-response-redirect.aspx` it has some great examples. I guess you can use one of those to redirect to the https URL.